# Finding an answer according to " Fibonacci sequence"

Tags: java, math, arraylist, fibonacci

Please have a look at the following code

```
package Euler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Problem2
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int firstNumber=1;
        int secondNumber=2;
        int thirdNumber = 0;

        int sum = 0;

        List array = new ArrayList();

        while(true)
        {

            if(thirdNumber>=400000)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                thirdNumber = firstNumber+secondNumber;
                System.out.println(thirdNumber);


                 if(thirdNumber%2==0)
                {
                    array.add(thirdNumber);
                }

                firstNumber = secondNumber;
                secondNumber = thirdNumber;
            }
        }

        for( int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
        {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(array.get(i).toString());

            sum = sum+num;
        }

        System.out.println("The Sum is: "+sum);
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to solve [this](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2) problem, from Project Euler, Here is the problem anyway.

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

This was the answer I got- 257112;

It says the answer is wrong. I don't know why that is. For your information, my native language is not English, and I didn't do math in English too. So I doubt whether I misunderstood the question.

Please help me to find the correct way to solve this. Thanks

Comment: @nhahtdh No, there are not many terms in the sequence smaller than four million. Works fine with `int`.

Comment: This is a project Euler problem, so people should avoid providing solutions.

Comment: The correct answer is sum = 4613732.  You ought to be sure that you have the Fibonnaci numbers correct before you worry about the sum.  See if you can create a list of values and get those right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million...

One problem is here:

```
if(thirdNumber>=400000)
```

That's not four million. You need one more zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Rest of the stuff are correct? I mean, am I following the correct Math way or not?

Comment: @user1484871: Well I've had a quick glance at it, and it looks OK, but this line is a bit... err... unnecessary: `int num = Integer.parseInt(array.get(i).toString());` Why both converting to a string and then parsing it back to an int? It was already an `Integer` at the start. Just call `intValue`. And use a generic list so you don't need to cast. Also you could calculate the sum as you go instead of storing the integers in a list then summing at the end. The list is not needed at all.

Comment: It seems also that you are not including the term `2` in the sum. The first term you add the the array appears to be `8`.

Comment: That was awesome! Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much more efficient by

- calculating the sum while calculating the Fibonacci numbers (So you don't have to store them)
- If you did use a collection, use generics instead of converting to a String and parsing it (this is amazingly inefficient)
- note that every third value is even, so you don't need to check for even.

Try

```
long a = 1, b = 1, c, sum = 0;
while ((c = a + b) < 4000000) {
    sum += c;
    a = b + c;
    b = c + a;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```